# How does the SQL connection in an application should be called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Back to basics.

I have an application written in c# and I am using the sqlClient to connect to database.

I have several methods and I usually open the connection in a try catch block

```
try{
    **open connection**
   //Mehod1()
   //Method2()
   ........
 }catch(exception){
   //Do something
 }finally{
  **close connection**
 }
```

**The Problem is that there are a lot connections in pool.**

I am using master page and in master page I am loading the menu from database (different menu for each user).

Then in main pages I  open again a connection to get the rest data.

In the middle of the page it may be a method that need again to connect to database.

**My Question is**

Is this a good practise?

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a better practise to avoid multiple connections?
What about singleton pattern?

Thanks in advance

> ***SOLUTION***
>
> I found the reason!!!
>
> I had forgot to close a connection.
>
> I was sure that I had close it, but
>   sometimes you can't be so sure.

Thanks everyone for your responses

Comment: Connection pooling is a 'good' thing.

Comment: How many connections do you have in the pool ? The connection pool is normally a good thing as it allows you to efficiently "open/close" several connections. A singleton for the a database connection in a web application is a bad thing - take advantage of the connection pooling rather.

Comment: The problem in my issue is that the connection didn't reused  from pooling.
It creates every time a new one.

Comment: "It creates every time a new one." How do you measure?

Comment: I have a sql script to observe the connections

Answer (score 3):

Since the connection is pooled you don't need to "reuse" it in different methods.

I use the following code:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("your-connectionstring"))
{
  // Do your stuff here...
}
```

`Using` is just a short hand way of writting `try-catch-finally`. It is used for disposable objects.

And this can go into each method.

EDIT: Using the connection from the pool is not hurting performance either. All connection information are cached anyway. So just use the SqlConnection on an atomic level.

It's a good thing though to have the ConenctionString handling in a more generic way...

Comment: I agree with you but I don't know why the connection didn't reused from pooling. It creates every time a new one.

If I open a connection then I have one connection in pooling and when I'll need one more connection then I'll get it from pooling.

But in my case it creates one more connection in pooling.

Is this normal behaviour ?

Comment: You might get some more answers here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx. If the connection string is 100% the same the connection has to be from the same pool.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't dispose your SqlConnections
try this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{ }
```

this syntax will call method `Dispose()` automatically for you. [Using statement details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

**UPDATE:**

A bit more info about this methods you may find here: [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx), [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.dispose.aspx)

Basically the difference is that method `Dispose()` called method `Close()`, but before it is cleaning some resources and removing connection from the pool [details here](http://www.jstawski.com/archive/2009/03/12/1210.aspx).

As you see `Dispose()` doing a bit more than `Close()`. So if you going to reuse connection later use method `Close()` if not destroy that completely using method `Dispose()` which is automatically getting called if you using the syntax above.

Comment: Is there any different for pooling between dispose and close?

Answer (score 0):

Using() as said above is a good way to new up a new object of a class that implements IDisposable. But with that being said , you cannot leave you connection open once you done. You have finite number of connection in the pool and leaving a connection unclosed can starve other SPIDs which are waiting for active connection which will finally timeout. So you should

1. Always have atomic and small transactions .
2. Close when done.

There is DAAB (data access application block) from Microsoft Enterprise Library which can be used as helper to open and close connections + do many other DB related tasks easily. Here it is 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511547.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally I believe that is better the use of using than try catch block, as it's easy to forget to close any connection.

I'll check out the DAAB as you suggested me.